# Are there any libraries with convenience extension methods for using generics with old .net libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, generics, extension-methods

When writing code for Winforms I keep having to cast everything to get a generic IEnumerable.

```
resultsListView
    .SelectedIndices
    .Cast<int>()
    .ToArray();

treeView1.Nodes.Cast<TreeView>().Where...

var items = listView1.Items.Cast<ListView>();
```

Now, if I were to have made a typo like I have above I wouldn't notice until the code runs. (I.e. it's dynamically typed.)

To get around this I've written some utility extension methods like this:

```
resultsListView
    .SelectedIndices
    .AsEnumerable()
    .ToArray();

treeView1.Nodes.AsEnumerable().Where...

var items = listView1.Items.AsEnumerable();
```

Example extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> AsEnumerable(this TreeNodeCollection source)
{
    return source.Cast<TreeNode>();
}
```

Now, I've just written a method here and there, and there are quite a few classes in .NET library, so I was hoping that some nice soul would've done this already? So how about it?

Are there any libraries with convenience extension methods for using generics with old .net libraries?

### Edit:

Well actually, to take advantage of the static typing that the classes already provide (often), this is how I've *really* written them:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> AsEnumerable(this TreeNodeCollection source)
    {
        AssertTypesMatch(source, (s) => s.AsEnumerable(), (s) => s[0]);
        return source.Cast<TreeNode>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ListViewItem> AsEnumerable(this ListView.ListViewItemCollection source)
    {
        AssertTypesMatch(source, (s) => s.AsEnumerable(), (s) => s[0]);
        return source.Cast<ListViewItem>();
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.Conditional("ALWAYZ__EXKLUDE_ME_")]
    private static void AssertTypesMatch<TSource, TItem>(TSource t1, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TItem>> f2, Func<TSource, TItem> f1)
    {
    }
```

Comment: "When writing code for Winforms I keep having to cast everything to get a generic IEnumerable." ... cannot resist pointing out that it's still the same with WPF.

Comment: Perhaps a single `Cast<T, E>(this T source, Func<T, E> elem)` extension method would be useful? It would ignore `elem`, only using it for determining the type of the result, so that you could call it as `treeView1.Nodes.Cast(n => n[0])`. This uses the same idea as you're using in your `AssertTypesMatch`, but does not require you to create a new method for every possible non-generic `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Hm, pretty cool idea actually, doesn't look that terribly either. Not quite as convenient though. Certainly more typesafe than explicitly naming the type.